# Problem with 'while' loop and list index in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with my loop. I would like to set `nominal diameter` as value from `nominal_diameters` list. For example my `calc_diameter=130` so I'd like that `nominal_diameter=125`. 
So far in this code I am getting `nominal_diameter = 0` .

What should I change in my loop?

```
import math

print('Welcome in PipeDiameter program. It helps you to choose the right size of pipe for'
      ' sewerage pressure systems.')
flow=round(float(input('Please enter your sewage flow [(m^3)/s]:')),2)
speed_assumed = 1
calc_diameter=round(math.sqrt(((4*flow)/((math.pi)*speed_assumed))*1000),2)
print(str(calc_diameter)+' mm')

nominal_diameters=[90,110,125,160,180,200,225,250,315,355,400,450,500,560,630,710,800]
inner_diameters=[(90-2*5,4),(110-2*6,6),(125-2*7,4),(160-2*9,5),(180-2*10,7),(200-2*11,9),
                 (225-2*13,4),(250-2*14,8),(315-2*18,7),(355-2*21,1),(400-2*23,7),(450-2*26,7),
                 (500-2*29,7),(560-2*33,2),(630-2*37,4),(710-2*42,1),(800-2*47,4)]

nominal_diameter=0
i=0

while nominal_diameters[i]<=calc_diameter<=nominal_diameters[i+1]:
    nominal_diameter=nominal_diameters[i]
    i=i+1
print(nominal_diameter)
```

Comment: Why if `calc_diameter=130` should `nominal_diameter=125`? And not 160? Or what if `calc_diameter=124`? Also what about thickness list?

Comment: do you really need this condition? calc_diameter<=nominal_diameters[i+1]?

Comment: The condition fails for the first check `90 <= 130 <= 110` and so the loop is never entered. Could you explain what you are trying to do in the loop? Is the `nominal_diameter` supposed to be the value in the list that is closest to the `calc_diameter`?

Comment: remove the second condition calc_diameter<=nominal_diameters[i+1] you will get the desiered output

Comment: @iGian for calc_diameter=130 should nominal_diameter=125, not 160 because it has connection with further calculation. speed_assumed is 1 in my example and this speed is minimum. In further I will calculate a real speed inside the pipe. To do that I need thickness list inner diameter. And as smaller pipe as speed is higher, this is why nominal_diameter should be lower than calc_diameter. You helped without knowing that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to while loop, since appears to be a select the problem:

```
nominal_diameters=[90,110,125,160,180,200,225,250,315,355,400,450,500,560,630,710,800]

calc_diameter = 130
select_diam = min([(abs(d-calc_diameter), d) for d in nominal_diameters ])[1]

print(select_diam) #=> 125
```

For `calc_diameter = 195` it returns `200`.

**How it works**

By [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) it maps the list of `nominal_diameters` to a list of tuples with this couple of values: the absolute (`abs()`) difference between the required diameter and the nominal diameter and the nominal diameter itself (`(abs(d-calc_diameter), d)`).

Then it pick the minimum (`min()`) tuple on the list, finally from the minimum pick the second element (`[1]`), which is the nominal diameter.

This is for example the map for `calc_diameter = 130`:

```
[(40, 90), (20, 110), (5, 125), (30, 160), (50, 180), (70, 200), (95, 225), (120, 250), (185, 315), (225, 355), (270, 400), (320, 450), (370, 500), (430, 560), (500, 630), (580, 710), (670, 800)]
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This does not work as intended. For `calc_diameter=195` you would get 180 and not 200.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if the condition is not satisfied for the first value the loop is never entered, and hence your nominal diameter will evaluate to 0. You can change your code as below

```html
while True:
        if nominal_diameters[i] <= calc_diameter <= nominal_diameters[i + 1]:
            nominal_diameter = nominal_diameters[i]
            break
        i = i + 1
```

This should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
while nominal_diameters[i] <= calc_diameter <= nominal_diameters[i+1]:
```

Assume that `calc_diameter = 300`, in that case the statement reads as

```
while 90 <= 300 <= 110:
```

Which will fail immediately, leaving you with `0`.

You can solve it by doing something like this:

```
for i in range(len(nominal_diameters)-1):
    if nominal_diameters[i] <= calc_diameter <= nominal_diameters[i+1]:
        nominal_diameter = nominal_diameters[i]
        break
else:
    if calc_diameter < nominal_diameters[0]:
        nominal_diameter = nominal_diameters[0]
    else:
        nominal_diameter = nominal_diameters[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that based on the `calc_diameter` you what to find what value of `nominal_diameters` list is the one closest to that. You could do this as follows (an example with `calc_diameter=130`):

```
import numpy as np

nominal_diameters=[90,110,125,160,180,200,225,250,315,355,400,450,500,560,630,710,800]
calc_diameter = 130

best_approx = np.argmin([np.abs(d-calc_diameter) for d in nominal_diameters]) # Provides the index in nominal_diameters with value closest to calc_diameter
print(nominal_diameters[best_approx]) # Outputs 125
```

Comment: I am getting error: 'AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'argmin'. Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Weird, numpy definitely has argmin and I tested this code and worked well for me.